# Test Firebase RealtimeDatabase using Jest

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs

My purpose is simply to test one function. I cannot figure out how to mock firebase properly. I try to keep the example with axios mocking from Jest docs. I have the following code:

**MusicService.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

const firebase = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
});

export class MusicService {
  static getAlbums() {
    return firebase.database().ref("albums").once("value")
    .then(snapshot => Object.values(snapshot.val()));
  }
}
```

**MusicService.test.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import { MusicService } from './MusicService';

jest.mock('firebase/app');
jest.mock('firebase/database');

test("test", () => {
  firebase.initializeApp.mockImplementation(() => {
    database: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        ref: jest.fn()
      }
    })
  });

  MusicService.getAlbums();
});
```

The problem is that I get the following error:
[image]

I tried to mock firebase.database.

```
test("test", () => {
  firebase.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      database: {

      }
    }
  });
  MusicService.getAlbums();
});
```

But in this case I get the error that says:

> TypeError: _app.default.mockImplementation is not a function.

I don't expect the working example will be given, but rather could you tell please, what exactly should I mock? The whole firebase library or maybe the part where my function starts -  `return firebase.database()`.

Answer (score 8):

I have figured out. I should mock only those modules, a function I am going to test, depends on. For example, I want to test `getAlbums` function. It uses `initializeApp` function which is imported from `firebase/app` module in `MusicService.js`. So when `initializeApp` function is being called it should return an object containing `database` function which in turn returns an object with `ref` and `once` functions. Code:

**MusicService.test.js**.

```
import { MusicService } from "./FirebaseService";

jest.mock("firebase/app", () => {
  const data = { name: "unnamed" };
  const snapshot = { val: () => data };
  return {
    initializeApp: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      database: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        ref: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        once: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot))
      })
    })
  };
});

test("getAlbums function returns an array", async () => {
  const data = await MusicService.getAlbums();
  expect(data.constructor).toEqual(Array);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my current mock implementation for firebase.js.
for me it is working fine.

```
const firebase = jest.genMockFromModule('firebase');

firebase.initializeApp = jest.fn();

const data = { name: 'data' };
const snapshot = { val: () => data, exportVal: () => data, exists: jest.fn(() => true) };

firebase.database = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  ref: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  on: jest.fn((eventType, callback) => callback(snapshot)),
  update: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot)),
  remove: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  once: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot)),
});

firebase.auth = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  currentUser: true,
  signOut() {
    return Promise.resolve();
  },
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (password === 'sign' || password === 'key') {
        resolve({ name: 'user' });
      }
      reject(Error('sign in error '));
    });
  },
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (password === 'create' || password === 'key') {
        resolve({ name: 'createUser' });
      }
      reject(Error('create user error '));
    });
  },
});

export default firebase;
```

Comment: seems ref now gets a parameter, so I get this error `ref is not a function`